# Matlab Coding finding zeros without using fzero or roots function

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, matlab, cubics

So i am a completely new at Matlab. I'm basically suppose to develop a function in Matlab that finds the zeros of a cubic polynomial. real and complex. I'm pasting below what I have so far.

I started off by using the bisection method and it's not working for a basic polynomial i know the roots to.

```
function rts = cubicxx(C)
a = C(1);
b = C(2);
c = C(3);
d = C(4);
start = 1e20;
last = -1e20;
rts = [8000 ; 8000; 8000];
rcount = 0;
f = @(x) (a).*x^3 + (b).*x^2 + (c).*x + d ;

%for loop 
 %   x(i)=
  %  i = i+1;
%end

 %for rts='a' : 'c', rts, maybe something i will use later


tol = 10^(-6)
while (rcount < 4) %while true Starting off with the Bisection method.
    p = (start + last)/2;
    if f(p) == 0
        rcount = rcount + 1;
        rts (rcount) = p; 
        break; end
    if p-start <tol 
        break; end
    if f(start)*f(p)> 0
        start = p;
    else
        last = p;
    end
end
 end
```

the "rcount" is suppose to help me print the roots. Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you break after p - start < tol there are unsaved zeros between start and last. If you know that there is zero in $[x_1 - \epsilon, x_1 + \epsilon]$ you can say one zero is $x \approx x_1$.

Comment: so right after  
    if p-start <tol  
    rcount = rcount +1;
    rts(rcount) = 1;
    break; end

Comment: How do you define $z > 0\;$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You should also notice that almost always f(p) ~= 0 even if f(p) is mathematically zero (because of numerical imprecision) .

Comment: @Reactant right. Well, here's another problem I'm having is setting the start and last value. By the nature of the cubic, my professor says we know that there will be some point it cross over the x-axis. Therefore, I picked a far off point as possible. if I changed my last = -1e30 i would like to think it would make a difference?

Comment: putting ridiculous large numbers into `f` is a bad idea. The way you compute the polynomial is unstable. Instead try something like $f(\pm r)$ for $r = 1,2,4,8, \dotsc$. Why do you implement bisection for cubic equation anyway? There is a [cubic formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html)!

Comment: @user251257 writing a code for the Cubic Formula seems beyond me. I tried writing it out but I didn't get anywhere. What do you mean by f(±r)  how would I write that in Matlab

Comment: Assume the leading coefficient $a$ is positiv. Then, something like
  
    r1 = 1;
    while f(r1) <= 0 && r1 < inf;
     r1 = 2*r1;
    end;

    r2 = 1;
    while f(-r2) >= 0 && r2 < inf;
     r2 = 2*r;
    end;
    
Then, $f$ has a sign change on $[r_1, r_2]$. Sorry for the formatting. Comments don't allow block code

Comment: @user251257 okay, so I've modifies my code a bit.
a1=1;
while f(a1) <= 0 && a1 < inf 
    a1=2*a1;
end
b1=1;
while f(-b1)>=0 && b1 < inf
    b1=2*b1;
end