# Finding Zeros of cubic without using fzero or roots in Matlab

Tags: roots, matlab, quadratics, cubics

okay, so I've modifies my code a bit.

```
function rts = cubicSS(C)
a = C(1);
b = C(2);
c = C(3);
d = C(4);
rts = [90000 ; 90000 ; 90000];
f = @(x) a.*x^3 + b.*x^2 + c.*x + d;
a1=1;
while f(a1) <= 0 && a1 < inf 
    a1=2*a1;
end
b1=1;
while f(-b1)>=0 && b1 < inf
    b1=2*b1;
end
rcount = 0;
tol = 1e-6;
a1=1;
while f(a1) <= 0 && a1 < inf 
    a1=2*a1;
end
b1=1;
while f(-b1)>=0 && b1 < inf
    b1=2*b1;
end

 while 1  
            p = (a1+b1)/2;
            if f(p) == 0
                rcount = rcount + 1;
                rts(rcount) = p;
                break; end
            if p-a1 <tol
               break; end
            if f(a1)*f(p)> 0
                a1=p;
            else
                b1=p;
            end
        end
    end
```

However, whenever I run this code, I don't get any roots back. right now I'm setting `C =[ 1 -3 3 -1]` just to test it out. My plan is that after i find one root, I will use deconv function to do long division and then use the quadratic formula on my newly found polynomial .

wanted to know what bugs or errors could possibly be in my code

Comment: why do you compute `a1` and `b1` twice? The range with the sign change is form `-b1` to `a1`, not from `b1` to `a1`. Just set `b1 = -b1` after the second `while` loop. It is also a bad idea to check for `f(p)==0`. Better `abs(f(p)) <= rtol` where `rtol = tol*max(f(a1), -f(b1))` for the initial `a1` and `b1`.

Comment: @user251257 so when i set rtol = tol*max(f(a1), -f(b1)) i wanted to see what rtol would be and it says its infinity. which is something I don't want. Thank you for correcting my interval mistake

Comment: what values do you get for `a1`, `b1`, and `f(a1)`, `f(b1)`?

Comment: @user251257 how do i check that? take away the ; ?

Comment: yes, just output the values.

Comment: @user251257 just some more background information: i've set b1= -1 an still not getting the start and end points that I want. if i go ahead and set b1= -b1 it's giving me an error

Comment: wait, i will just check the code in matlab

Comment: @user251257 also, i've updated the code i've written a bit by adding deconv function is there an easier way you and I can communicate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25941/discussion-between-dean3794-and-user251257).

Answer (score 1):

Since you set your left endpoint as a positive and found its position by taking $f(-b1)$, you start out in the range $[1,2]$ instead of the range $[-1,2]$ like you want. After finding the absolute value of $b1$, make sure it is negative, since that is how your programme works.

Aside from that, you are setting your tolerance based on the distance from $p$ to $a1$, which will eventually terminate, but you never set the value of the root for the "tolerant" version.

I didn't see anything else wrong here.

NOTE, though, that your example cubic will require complex roots.

Answer (score 1):

**The code for `a1` and `b1` in the following is only for cubic polynomial with *non-zero* leading coefficient!**

So, I clean up the code. It was basically right. I've no idea why you get `inf` for the function values. I change following things

1. I filled `rts` with nan. Otherwise it was little difficult to read normal size numbers and 90000 the same time.
2. I parenthesis $f$. It is called *Horner's method* and helps against rounding errors. It is just a rule of thumb and won't always help.
3. `b1` is always negative.
4. `tol_interval` controls, when is the interval from `b1` to `a1` so small that you consider `b1` equals `a1`.
5. `tol_func` controls, when is the absolute function value is so small that you consider it zero.

Play with `tol_interval` and `tol_func` and you see how *ill conditioned* finding zeros of polynomial can be. In particular your example, where $1$ is a zero of multiplicity $3$.

Here is the code:

```
function rts = cubicSS(C)
    a = C(1);
    b = C(2);
    c = C(3);
    d = C(4);
    rts = [nan ; nan ; nan];
    f = @(x) ((a .* x + b) .* x + c) .* x + d;

    s = sign(a);

    a1 = 1; 
    while s*f(a1) <= 0 && a1 < inf
        a1=2*a1;
    end

    b1 = -1;
    while s*f(b1) >= 0 && b1 > -inf
        b1 = 2*b1;
    end

    rcount = 0;
    tol = 1e-6;
    tol_interval = tol*abs(a1 - b1);
    tol_func = tol*max(abs(f(a1)), abs(f(b1)));

    while 1
        p = (a1+b1)/2;
        if abs(f(p)) <= tol_func
            rcount = rcount + 1;
            rts(rcount) = p;
            break; 
        end

        if abs(a1 - b1) <= tol_interval         
            break; 
        end

        if f(a1)*f(p)> 0
            a1=p;
        else
            b1=p;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: mean while, I added the deconv function and quadratic function

Comment: wow, you're the best. you should be a Matlab Youtube instructor!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your polynomial is
$f(x) =-x^3-1$,
the initial loop
on $a1$
will overflow
since
$f(x) < 0$
for all $x \ge 0$.

Comment: well, it was written for $a > 0$ ... implicitly. See comments in the old thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361762/matlab-coding-finding-zeros-without-using-fzero-or-roots-function

Comment: So i'd have to add a case here if a < 0 and then insert another while loop with flipped conditions? @user251257

Comment: @dean3794: yepp

Comment: @user251257 keeping a1= -1 (within this new condition While loop) or would a1 = 1 and only the while statement would switch with the b1 statement?

Comment: @dean3794: I just update the code in my answer